# Subgroups of Frobenius group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, frobenius-groups

Let $G=N\rtimes M$ be a finite Frobenius group with kernel $N$ and complement $M$. Suppose that $N$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$,  while $M$ is maximal in $G$. Is there a result which states something about the form of the subgroups of $G$? For instance, besides the subgroups of $N$, the subgroups of $M^g$ and the subgroups $NH$, where $1<H\leq M^g$, are there any other subgroups in $G$? As usual, $M^g$ denotes a conjugate of $M$.

Comment: For the subgroups containing $N$, you could just write $NH$ with $1 < H \le M^g$. But there could also be subgroups of the form $MH$ with $1 < M < N$ and $1 < H < M^g$ - they are also Frobenius groups, but with smaller kernel. For example, a Frobenius group of order $72$ with $|N|=9$ contains subgroups  of order $6$ . I think that's the only other possibility.

Comment: Thank you for this example!